# Setup Intellij to hot update jars and run Maven Appassembler

Tags: maven, jar, intellij-idea, appassembler

I want to setup *Intellij* to automatically do what I am doing from the command-line with maven repeatedly, which is to run `mvn package -DskipTests` to rebuild my jar and run the *Appassembler* Maven plugin to produce my runnable scripts. Ideally, all I want it to do is hot update the classes within the jar which I have changed.

I have figured out how to tell Intellij to create jars with the Artifact tab in Project Structure, but can I get Intellij to import this artifact information from the pom instead of me setting it up manually?

- It does auto-import pom changes, but never imported this artifact info.
- This would enable it to use the exact output name of what maven produces, so that whether I'm working from the command-line or IDE I can work with one set of outputs. (reason below)

*Appassembler* adds an additional step, which includes it copying all the dependencies into its target folder and producing the scripts. If Intellij can't trigger Appassembler, I was thinking maybe Appassembler could use symlinks instead and the when the jar as updated, my runnable app scripts would immediately be using that version. Or in the worse case, I only need to run this particular step from the command-line, the jar having already been built.

**Update**

In case it helps, here's how I use Appassembler in my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>package</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>assemble</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <programs>
          <program>
            <mainClass>com.foo.bar.Foobnobicator</mainClass>
            <name>gofoo</name>
          </program>
        </programs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks for the advice on the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Are you talking about the [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/index.html) ?

Comment: Yes, is "Appassembler Maven plugin" ambiguous?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the pom file? To see where you added appassembler-plugin ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, there it is. Hope that helps.